# tomcat Java NIO with concurrent slow TCP client connections

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, tcp

**My unsertanding**

Without NIO:
For every keepAlive connection server continue to block a thread.

With NIO:
This connector has a couple of poller threads used to keep the connection alive for all connected users while worker threads are called whenever data (a new HTTP request) is available

Now: 
If i have a simple servlet which return a 100 KB string to client(browser).

```
....
String HunderdKBString = "reallylongstring"
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(HunderdKBString);
....
```

If a client with 1 KB connection connects then it will take around 100 Sec to receive the string.
So is it that the java thread will be blocked for around 100 sec?

How does TCP buffer, Java `OutputStream` or `Writer` or other buffers affects the thread block time?

PS: using apache-tomcat-8.0.24 in centos 7 with oracle JDK 1.7.

EDIT: As mentioned thread does get blocked and buffer can reduce thread block time.. How to optimism tomcat/OS to reduce thread block time by using these buffer?

How one can detect in production environment if tomcat is starving of thread due to many slow connection client connected to it?

Comment: The discussion about NIO doesn't make sense. Within the Tomcat container, you don't get the choice to switch the IO technology. You have to use the synchronous Writer instance that Tomcat provides you. But I agree that many slow connections can be a serious real-world issue. How many concurrent connections do you expect? 100? 1000? 10000? 100000?

Comment: @Codo we work on the site which have spike load behaviour. suddenly 500 client can connect.which may translate to 500* (4 TCP connection from browser) = 2000 .. and yes many can be slow..

Comment: With 2000 parallel connections, the most pragmatic solution is to increase the number of Tomat worker threads to 2000 (or even more). Today's servers should easily handle so many threads. You might need to allocate sufficient memory to Tomcat though. It would be different if you we were talking about 100,000 connections.

Comment: Another option - provided you're response don't contain any user or session specific data and therefore are cachable - is to put nginx as a cache in front of Tomcat. nginx has the option to immediately consume the entire response and to forward it to the client at the given slow speed.

Comment: nginx might even work if your responses aren't cachable. Have a look at [Using Buffers to Free Up Backend Servers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching#using-buffers-to-free-up-backend-servers).

Comment: Take a look on reverse proxy (apache, nginx) features. Cache, load balancing... You can monitor your tomcat using Java Mission Control tool.

Comment: @BeñatBermejo thanks i didnt know about JMC .. cool..

Comment: I understand people are trying to help and using nginx or apache is certain configuration will help.. but i am still looking curious to know the impact of caches and slow connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it that the java thread will be blocked for around 100 sec?

Yes.

> How does TCP buffer, Java OutputStream or Writer or other buffers affect the thread block time?

If the buffer is large enough to hold the sent data, the sending thread won't block.

Comment: Can you please point me to resource on the how to optimism tomcat/OS to reduce thread block time by increase these different kind of buffers

Comment: I don't agree with @EJP's second statement: Buffers will only help if they are at OS level. Buffers in OutputStream or Writer classes won't help as they will still block once Tomcat tries to flush all outstanding data.

Comment: Rather than start tinkering with your buffers, you should reduce the request timeout to an acceptable level. If a user keeps the thread occupied for too long and it's causing starvation, then killing the threads for those users in time will solve your problem. Whether your problem is caused by the users or the files you're serving are just too large, there will likely be little optimisation possible on the OS side. Look more closely at your server's configuration.

Comment: @Codo My second statement is correct. I didn't say anything about buffers 'helping', and from the blocking point of view it makes no difference which buffer you're talking about. Once all buffers are full, a send will block.